# How can I write the same text to two separate file handles using Perl?

Tags: perl, text-files

I need to output the same text to two different files (it is a application requirement, which I am testing). Now, I do not wish to open two file handles, write two lines to each, then close them a dozen times in my code.

Is there a simple way, perhaps using a single line in Perl (but not in the CLI!), to send the same text to two different files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [IO::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/~kenshan/IO-Tee-0.64/Tee.pm).

From the documentation's example:

```
use IO::Tee;
$tee = IO::Tee->new($handle1, $handle2);
print $tee "foo", "bar";
```